# Provision Vagrant machine with mysql Puppet module

Tags: mysql, vagrant, puppet, puppetlabs-mysql

I am trying to provision a `Vagrant` machine using [this puppet module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql).

The `Hello world` is simple, its something like this:

```
class { '::mysql::server':
  root_password           => 'strongpassword',
  remove_default_accounts => true
}
```

But my main objective is, when you do `vagrant up` the first time, the `vagrant machine` will have a `mysql server` ready for external access and be able to accept external connections from the `host` with a specific user.

This is what I tried:

```
class { '::mysql::server':
    root_password           => 'strongpass',
    remove_default_accounts => false,
    override_options => {
      mysqld => { bind-address => '0.0.0.0'} //allow entry connections from any ip
    }
  }

//create a database called `mydb`, a user and a password
  mysql::db { 'mydb':
      user     => 'admin',
      password => 'secret',
      host     => '192.168.33.1',
    }

//assign it all the privileges to that user
  mysql_grant { 'admin@192.168.33.1/*.*':
    ensure     => 'present',
    options    => ['GRANT'],
    privileges => ['ALL'],
    table      => '*.*',
    user       => 'admin@192.168.33.1',
  }
```

This is the test I do in order to see if it worked:

- Destroy the vagrant machine if already exists: `vagrant destroy`
- Create the vagrant machine: `vagrant up`
- Try to connect with [MySQLWorkbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

**Question**

The weird thing is, when I try to do a connection, it is just not possible, but if I do a `vagrant reload --provision` then I am able to connect it with `MySQLWorkbech`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you confirm mysql service is running and you can connect from VM after the initial vagrant up ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yes, I can confirm that. I can do a `vagrant ssh` and then login into `mysql`.

Comment: What kind of OS are you on? Can you telent to that port? Is there a firewall?